# SharePoint 2013 - Search Service Application Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

We had search working on our server farm before, but then it crashed and one of the admins deleted the existing Search Service Application and created a new one.  After it was successfully created we started being plagued by this error.

> The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '82f5132f-5b11-446e-9fa0-190fb71606c9' in search application 'Search Service Application 250115' is in a good state and try again.

[image: aaa]

Can anyone help figure this out or give some pointers as to what to check try?

EDIT

It seems that the Admin Component isn't running that is causing this.Does anyone have any ideas how to get the admin component running?

Answer (score 1):

How was it created, through GUI or customized by PowerShell? Sometimes for me that may come up upon the first 10 minutes of creating the Search Service Application.

- Make sure the search service is on for the server hosting the administration component.
- Make sure the topology is correct and has a administration component.
- If the topology has an administration component, try to [reprovision it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mutaz/archive/2010/03/09/reprovision-service-applications.aspx)
- Try to delete the search service application and choose "Delete associated data" then create a new one through the GUI.

Comment: I create the SSA through the GUI.  Also deleted it (with associated data) and recreated another SSA through the GUI.  Same problem.

Comment: make sure your application pool account has access to the search service application (as administrator).

Comment: Seems I think i've found the culprit.  Updated main post.